# Secure logical AND using Ishai-Sahai-Wagner Scheme

Tags: randomness

I want to try to implement a secure AND the way it was described here:
https://eprint.iacr.org/2010/441.pdf

It says that there are two bits a and b and that they have been split into d+1 shares. How can I split a bit? I guess there isn't something more atomic than a bit, isn't it? Can you give me an example on how to do this?
I mean I could say that, for example:

Let $d$ be 4. Assume that $a$ = 1, then I can split it into the following 4 shares: $a_1 = 1, a_2 = 1, a_3 = 1, a_4 = 0$ because then it holds that $1 \mathbin{\oplus}1\mathbin{\oplus}1\mathbin{\oplus}0 = 1 = a$. Is that what is meant with the $d$ shares? I assume these shares are random values?

I tried a first implementation of the secure AND as follows:

```
void SecAND(char a, char b, char* arr, char* brr)
{
  int i; int j;
  int d = 4;
  int r[4][4];
  int c[4];
  for(i = 0; i < d; i++)
  {
      for(j = i+1; j < d; j++)
      {
          srand(time(NULL));
          int rij = rand() % 2;
          r[i][j] = rij;
      }
  }

  for(i = 0; i < d; i++)
  {
      for(j = i+1; j < d; j++)
      {
          r[j][i] = (r[i][j]^(arr[i]*brr[j]))^(arr[j]*brr[i]);
      }
  }

  for(i = 0; i < d; i++)
  {
      c[i] = (arr[i]*brr[i]);

      for(j = 0; j < d; j++)
      {
          if(j != i)
          {
              c[i] = c[i] ^r[i][j];
          }
      }
  }
```

}

Can this be correct?

Comment: "Is that what is meant with the d shares?" ​ Roughly, although they might need a different [method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secret_sharing) with special properties. ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: @RickyDemer My problem is that I am not sure how to get these shares...I could use a brootforce approach but sure there is a better one...

Answer (score 2):

"Splitting into $d + 1$ shares" is mentioned in the Introduction, right after a reference to secret sharing schemes and mentioning threshold property. So, this particular IACR preprint is not the best source on secret sharing. I'd suggest to start from Shamir secret sharing algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

ISW Algorithm for implementation of a secure AND gate:
[image: ISW Algorithm]

for having secure AND gate, you should compute encoding for $c=\sum_{i,j} a_i b_j$ as below:

$c=a_i b_j \oplus z_{ij}$

that $z_{ij}$ for $i<j$ is random and for $i>j$ is:

$z_{ij}=(z_{ji} \oplus a_i b_j)\oplus a_j b_i$

for example, below image is an AND gate with 2 input shares (s=2):
[image: s=2]

or below picture is AND gate with s=3 input shares:
[image: s=3]

Note: source of images:https://eprint.iacr.org/2015/719